# Foreign key to table in different dbcontext with Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

How can I add a foreign key reference to a table in a different `DbContext` with Entity Framework Core?

```
class DonationContext : DbContext
{
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public string DonationType { get; set; }
    public string Desc { get; set; }
    public int? ChackID { get; set; }
    public Check Check { get; set; }
    public int? DonorCreditCardID { get; set; }
    public DonorCreditCard DonorCreditCard { get; set; }
    public string fundraisedBy;
    [NotMapped]
    public string FundraisedBy
}

public class DonorContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<DonorCreditCard> DonorCreditCards { get; set; }
    public DbSet<DonorAddress> DonorAddresss { get; set; }
    public DbSet<DonorPhoneNumber> DonorPhoneNumbers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<DonorEmailAddress> DonorEmails { get; set; }
    public DbSet<DonorFileAttachment> DonorFileAttachments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Donor> Donors { get; set; }
}
```

I want to reference the `DonorCreditCardID` column in the `DonationContext` to the `DonorCreditCards` table in the `DonorContext`. the migration builder wants to create a new table `DonorCreditCards`

Comment: Why don't you have one context for your entire DB?

Comment: I want to keep it more organized

Comment: Organized in what way?  Maybe you could make it a partial class if you just want to keep related `DbSet`s in separate files.

Comment: It's perfectly fine (if a little odd) to have multiple `DbContext` classes for the same database, but they must all be completely "self-contained".  There can be no navigation properties to entities that are not part of the `DbContext`.  You can create the Foreign-Key fields without matching navigation properties, and add the constraints manually using migrations.

Comment: If you are using code first, to implement this I had to write a custom SQL command in my migration file which created this foreign key

Comment: @ShloimeRosenblum did you came to any solution?

Comment: I vaguely remember JP Smith in Entity Framework Core in Action having multiple DbContexts while following a DDD approach. I think he used views to deal with the type of scenario when you want to reference an entity in a different domain.

Comment: Just found the section. Smith says that when an entity class is configured as view EF Core marks it as read-only enforcing DDD. You have the table only updateable in the Domain you consider it part of, and specific properties in views in others.